# node.js can resolve commonjs file path after typescript compilation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

My typescript watcher/engine is broken and I thought it would be better to compile my .ts files myself and run them with node/node-watcher. Weirdly node can not handle resolving the module of my compiled entrypoint. Here is the main.js (build/src/main.js) I wan to run with `node main.js`:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const connectDb_1 = require("db/connectDb");
const app_1 = require("./app");
const config_1 = require("./config");
const logger_1 = require("./utils/logger");
const connectFirebase_1 = require("firebase/connectFirebase");
const firebase_service_1 = require("firebase/firebase-service");
async function main() {
    const log = (0, logger_1.logger)(__filename);
    try {
        const mongo = await (0, connectDb_1.connectDb)();
        const firebase = (0, connectFirebase_1.connectFirebase)();
        const firebaseService = (0, firebase_service_1.makeFireBaseService)(firebase);
        const app = await (0, app_1.connectApp)(mongo, firebaseService);
        app.listen(config_1.config.port);
        log.info(`CorPatch server is up and running on port ${config_1.config.port}`);
    }
    catch (e) {
        {
            log.error(`${logger_1.LOG.AUDIT} Error starting corpatch server: ${e}`);
        }
    }
}
main();
```

See the "db/connectDb" require on line 3? Thats where it break with:

```sh
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'db/connectDb'
```

The directory and file exist exactly where they are specified. Here is my tsconfig as well:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es2018" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */,
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": false /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */,
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./build/" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "noImplicitAny": true /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */,
    "strictNullChecks": true /* Enable strict null checks. */,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true /* Enable strict checking of function types. */,
    "strictBindCallApply": true /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */,
    "noImplicitThis": true /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */,
    "alwaysStrict": true /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */,

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true /* Report errors on unused locals. */,
    // "noUnusedParameters": true /* Report errors on unused parameters. */,
    // "noImplicitReturns": true /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */,
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */,

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
    "baseUrl": "./src" /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */,
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [
    // "./node_modules/@types",
    // ] /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */,
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "blueprint-templates"]
  // "include": ["src"]
}
```

I feel it must be something embarrassingly easy but I really cant get it working :(

Comment: So do you have https://www.npmjs.com/package/db installed, because that's what your code is asking for.. or is `db/connectDb` local  if so you would need `./db/connectDb`

Comment: There is no package named 'db'. This is a file under ./db/connectDb.js
It somehow cant resolve that there is no './' or something similar. The typescript code is good as it worked before with ts-node.
I will try to compile the output not to a specific build directory though. MAybe that will help.

Comment: Your not understanding how `require` works,   a reference like `db/connectDb` means uses a package called `db`,  in fact it's this package -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/db   if you want to access local files you need to use either relative or absolute paths.  More info on how modules are resolved -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-nodejs-resolves-modules